# Google Sheet to PDF Get Only Active Sheet/Tab

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script converts pdf in inside the folder which is fine.

[image]

There are three tabs on this sheet when the function run. 
Merge all the tab in pdf and save in the drive folder with active sheet tab name

`var pdfName = "Invoice " + sheetName.getRange("d6").getValue();`

What I want

**When I run the script only active tab/sheet convert in pdf**. and not marge all tab in pdf.

```
function PDF() {
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var folderID = "1_gA4D7ybJ60dfgsdfgdsfInqVoo9D769cqmAnJI7g7";
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jBl_82etnHsdfgsdfgsdfgsdgcjaCpcTG6VvhKYNNrQQXJMUUOQkFGfORY/edit#gid=1167579479');
  
  var pdfName = "Invoice " + sheetName.getRange("d6").getValue(); 
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  //Copy whole spreadsheet
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))
  //delete redundant sheets
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  
  //save to pdf
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  //Delete the temporary sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Your current solution is not the proper way to create a pdf of a sheet. You need to use [getOAuthToken()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getoauthtoken) and [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params).
- Also I improved your script in many different ways. You are defining variables you are not using anywhere. And also you don't need to create a copy of the spreadsheet file and then delete it. You can simply create a pdf file of your source spreadsheet directly.
- The following script will create a pdf file of the active sheet. Keep in mind that the active sheet is the sheet selected in the `UI`.

---

### Solution:

```
function PDF(){
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sss.getActiveSheet();
  var ssID = sss.getId();
  var shID = sheet.getSheetId().toString();
  var folderID = "1_gA4D7ybJ60dfgsdfgdsfInqVoo9D769cqmAnJI7g7";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var pdfName = "Invoice " + sheet.getRange("d6").getValue(); 
  var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=pdf&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var newFile = folder.createFile(result.getBlob()).setName(pdfName)
}
```

Comment: const currentDate = new Date();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet5");
  ws.appendRow([currentDate,newFile.getUrl()]);

actually, I am appendRow through "var" newFile. How can I fix

Comment: @ManishS see my updated answer (last line). You can use `newFile.getUrl()`.

Comment: getOAuthToken() new for me A4 how to use 

`   '&size=letter' +
    '&portrait=true' +
    '&fitw=true&source=labnol' + 
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + 
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + 
    '&fzr=false' + 
    '&top_margin=0.00' + 
    '&bottom_margin=0.00' + 
    '&left_margin=0.00' + 
    '&right_margin=0.00' + 
    '&gridlines=false'  `

Comment: @ManishS Please could you post a new question because stackoverflow does not allow for follow-up questions. Thanks a lot and sorry for the incovenience.